# Why does my program stop responding and crashing?

Tags: python-3.x, crash, pygame

I was just trying to learn some PyGame which will be needed for my coming project so I would like to know why this sample piece of code is crashing and how I can fix it.

I've tried looking online and haven't found a working solution.

```
import pygame

# Initialise pygame
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# pygame.font.init()
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)

# Colours
BLACK = (0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE  = (0,   0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255,   0)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)

# Screen Size
size = [400, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Initialise Variables
done = False

class Unit:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack

class Infantry(Unit):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack):
        super().__init__(name, hp, attack)

    def attack_turn(self):
        self.hp -= self.attack
        text_surface = myFont.render(self.name + " has " + str(self.hp) + " health points left!", True, (255, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text_surface, (0, 0))
        # print(self.name + " has " + str(self.hp) + " health points left!")
        x = input("Press ENTER to continue!")

player = Infantry("Panzer", 110, 13)  # The attack set here is for the enemy.
enemy = Infantry("T-14", 100, 30)  # The attack set here is for the player.

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    while player.hp > 0 and enemy.hp > 0:
        player.attack_turn()
        enemy.attack_turn()

    done = True

if player.hp > enemy.hp:
    # print(player.name + " wins!")
    text_surface = myFont.render(player.name + " wins!", False, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (100, 100))
else:
    # print(enemy.name + " wins!")
    text_surface = myFont.render(enemy.name + " wins!", False, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (100, 100))
```

I hoped that the code would at least run so I could work off there but it's not even doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do another loop inside the main loop. The inner loop prevents the event handling, get rid of it. It is sufficient to check if the game has finished at the end of the main loop:

```py
done = False
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    player.attack_turn()
    enemy.attack_turn()

    if player.hp <= 0 or enemy.hp <= 0:
        done = True

    pygame.display.flip()
```

`input` does not do what you want it is not an input to the game window. Delete it and sperate the `attack` method to on method which calculates the new health and a ne method `draw`, which "blit" the text:

```py
class Infantry(Unit):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, attack):
        super().__init__(name, hp, attack)

    def attack_turn(self):
        self.hp -= self.attack

        ### x = input("Press ENTER to continue!") <----- delete

    def draw(self):
        text_surface = myFont.render(self.name + " has " + str(self.hp) + " health points left!", True, (255, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text_surface, (0, 0))
```

Use the [`pygame.KEYUP`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) event to check if the `pygame.K_RETURN` key was pressed.
Further do the all the drawing at the end of the main loop. Use [`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) to fill `screen` by a single color (clear the screen). Then draw the text. Finally use [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) to update the full display:

e.g.

```py
done = False
count = 0
while not done:

    attack = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                attack = True

    if attack:
        if count % 2 == 0:
            player.attack_turn()
        else:
            enemy.attack_turn()
        count += 1

    if player.hp <= 0 or enemy.hp <= 0:
        done = True

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    if count % 2 == 0:
        player.draw()
    else:
        enemy.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```